# How can pass state variable between components REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 components A and B.
How can pass a variable from component A to component B ?

**ComponentA.js**

```
const ComponentA = () => {

    //INSET
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    //GET HEADER HEIGHT
    const [heightHeader, setHeightHeader] = useState(false)


    return (
    <View 
    onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { height } = nativeEvent.layout
    setHeightHeader(height)
    }}>
    </View>
      )
    }
    
export default ComponentA
```

> I want to get from `const [heightHeader, setHeightHeader] = useState(false)`
> the **heightHeader** variable

**ComponentB.js**

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';

const ComponentB = () => {


return (
<View style={{
      flex:1
      }}>


<View style={{
flex:1,
paddingTop: heightHeader,
}}>
</View>
</View>
  )
}

export default ComponentB
```

> I want to get **heightHeader** variable from ComponentA to ComponentB.

*The 2 Components isn't in the same file

Answer (score 0):

Use redux for maintaining global state.
OR
Use pass props feature provided by React Navigation like this :

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation: { navigate } }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the home screen of the app</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', {heightHeader:heightHeader })
        }
        title="Go to Brent's profile"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

For more follow [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/)

Comment: No this is only for screens in navigation stack. I want  pass props between components as components not as stack screens.